# Maven - Replace property in project.pom file when installing in repository

Tags: maven-2

I have a parent project that defines a property, for example:

```
    <properties>
        <myproject-version>1.0</myproject-version>
    </properties>
```

In a 'child' project I use

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-modules</artifactId>
    <version>${myproject-version}</version>
</parent>
```

Everything works nice, but when Maven installs jar in repository, it creates pom like

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-modules</artifactId>
    <version>${myproject-version}</version>
</parent>
```

And I need that value of my-version to be replaced with 1.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

Is there any way to do that? I need 1.0 because of some compilation problems that occure when other projects use my project as dependency. (They look for a version ${myproject-version} instead of '1.0'

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm surprised to see this even working. A version **must** be specified in the parent tag (otherwise there is no way to know which version to pull from the repository) but that version should **not** be defined in terms of data defined in the parent pom, otherwise an obvious problem occurs: the parent pom would be needed to determine which parent pom is needed.

So I don't think there is any way to do what you are trying to do and, to be honest, I think its a bad idea.