# Property on maven when installed on repository are not replaced

Tags: maven, maven-3

It seems a bad practice to put a property on the parent pom and to reference it on your child pom

eg

on **parent pom.xml**

```
 <my.related.version>3.3.0.ga</my.related.version>
```

on **myproject/pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.related</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.related</artifactId>
    <version>${my.related.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

when you install and deploy myproject on maven repository and you reference it froma  second project outside your workspace, you can "crox"

> Could not transfer artifact
>   my.related:my.related:pom:${my.related.version}

**I don't uderstand why?**

How to solve?  NOTE: The question is related to

1. [Maven - Replace property in project.pom file when installing in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104432/maven-replace-property-in-project-pom-file-when-installing-in-repository) that has not a real explaination.
2. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2971?focusedCommentId=169243&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_169243

**Has it been solved on recent maven version? Which is the best practice?**

Comment: giusy it seems that you know the response :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to configure `dependencyManagement` in parent *pom.xml*

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>my.related</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.related</artifactId>
    <version>${my.related.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and `dependency` without version in *myproject/pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.related</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.related</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

More information: [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: @giusy as MariuszS said put on parent pom. I don't think why but it should be a bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2971 .. or not

Comment: Why are you defining a dependency with a property in the dependencyManagement? With the dependecyManagement you have exactly a single point of changing.

Comment: @khmarbaise You are right, but sometimes this is more readable to have all versions in one place (properties).